# JPA foreign key column name

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private String mail;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<UserGroup> userGroups;
}

@Embeddable
public class UserGroupPK {
    private String mail;
    private String role;
}

@Entity
public class UserGroup {
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserGroupPK id;
    private String field;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("mail")
    private User user;
}
```

Hibernate creates two tables: user(mail, password) and usergroup(user_mail, role, field).

I need to rename user_mail column to mail. I tried to add `@Column(name="mail")` in UserGroupPK but nothing.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate to generate the schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, the following should work:

```
@Entity
public class UserGroup {
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserGroupPK id;
    private String field;

    @ManyToOne(referencedColumnName = "mail")
    @JoinColumn(name = "mail")
    private User user;
}
```

See the corresponding paragraph [5.1.7.1. Using a foreign key or an association table](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) in the hibernate documentation:

> The @JoinColumn attribute is optional, the default value(s) is the concatenation of the name of the relationship in the owner side, _ (underscore), and the name of the primary key column in the owned side. In this example [user_mail] because the property name is [user] and the column id [(actually, the referencedColumnName)] of [User] is [mail].

*(I replaced the values in the [] brackets.)*

Please note, that your User entity doesn't have a primary key, which is probably not a good idea. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: With @JoinColumn it works. Is @JoinColumn alternative to @MapsId or Can I use them together? JPA 2.0 specification use MapsId in these cases. PS: I forgot to add @Id to User entity during transcription

Comment: @Alf: `@MapsId` is only used, if (a part of) the primary key is also a foreign key. So in your case, you should be able to use it (since you've added the @Id attribute to User now). I would assume, that you can combine `@MapsId` and `@JoinColumn` in this case, but I haven't tested that special combination yet. Could you try that for me, please?

Comment: Hi Chris, I tried @MapsId and @JoinColumn combination and works fine. Thank you.

Comment: I found out that @MapsId and @JoinColumn combination works in Hibernate but not in EclipseLink